# Displaying multiple html text box values in an ascending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I am using a HTML page where I have multiple textbox inputs, lets say five for example. I have a submit button. Once I enter all values in the text boxes and hit submit, i want all the values to be displayed in the area below submit button on the document in an ascending order. I want to sort all the values to display as result. I just used an array to test if my concept is right, but no luck. Anyone could help is highly appreciated.

This is the code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var txt = new array[];
    var txt[0] = $('input:text[name=text1]').val();
    var txt[1] = $('input:text[name=text2]').val();
    var txt[2] = $('input:text[name=text3]').val();
    var txt[3] = $('input:text[name=text4]').val();
    var txt[4] = $('input:text[name=text5]').val();
    txt.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('txt[i]').value + ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you attempted

Comment: The page reloads when you submit the form, so this sounds like something that is more suited for a serverside language, unless you're using ajax.

Comment: Greg and @codehorse thank you for your quick reply. I tried both of yours code. But seem like when i click button it is not calling the function itself..

Comment: Your code has nothing to write the values back to the document. Similar what user codehorse showed you have to output the values of your array $(txt.join(", ")).appendTo('.results-div');

Comment: Are you sure you understand this part of your code `for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) { document.getElementById('txt[i]').value + ' '; }`

To help you learn javascript please explain what you think it does?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree i have never used javascript before, this is my first time and learning this from tutorial. Let me tell you what i udnerstand this code is, and if i am wrong you can help me. I am trying to store text box values in an array and with the for loop i m trying to just display the array value to the document. Help me if i am not getting it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be correct, except for the line `document.getElementById('txt[i]').value + ' ';`. There's nothing writing the values back to the document.

First, starting with the selector, you need to change `'txt[i]'` to `'text'+i`,  because the browser is looking for an element with id `txt[i]` and finding nothing, thus doing nothing. Also, you should use jQuery, since it makes everything more concise.

Then, to write back to the document, you need to set the value. What your current code (`.value + ' ';`) does is it gets a value, then adds it to the string `' '`, then the statement ends. What you need to do is to set the value of the string, with jQuery (`.val(txt[i]);`) or stock Javascript (`.value = txt[i];`).

So, to conclude, just swap the code inside the for loop in your code with this line:

```
$("input:text[name=text"+i+"]").val(txt[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.text-1, .text-2`, etc are the classes of your input fields. The `.val()` will get the user input of those once they click on your submit button. The last line creates a new div and appends the user input to the results div.

```
$('.submit-button').on('click', function() {
    aaa = $('.text-1').val();
    bbb = $('.text-2').val();
    ccc = $('.text-3').val();
    ddd = $('.text-4').val();
    eee = $('.text-5').val();
        $('<div>' + aaa + '<br />' + bbb + '<br />' + ccc + '<br />' + ccc + '<br />' + ddd + '<br />' + eee + '</div>').appendTo('.results-div');
});
```

Comment: This is the code I tried. i am using an array as this is just the code i m trying with five text box, my real application may have more than 50 text boxes.

Comment: This is the code:
     function myFunction()
  {
   var txt = new array[];
   
  var txt[0]=$('input:text[name=text1]').val();
  var txt[1]=$('input:text[name=text2]').val();
  var txt[2]=$('input:text[name=text3]').val();
  var txt[3]=$('input:text[name=text4]').val();
  var txt[4]=$('input:text[name=text5]').val();
  
  txt.sort();
  
  for (var i=0; i<txt.length; i++)
  {
  document.getElementById('txt[i]').value + ' ';
  }
  }

Comment: You have some typos: `aaa = $('.text-1').val();` to get value for the first textbox is ok but `bbb = $('.text-1').val();` has to be `bbb = $('.text-2').val();` unless you want to read the same value again or in case you have many textboxes with the same class it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle that does what I think you want done:

http://jsfiddle.net/KjHB3/3/

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="text3" id="text3" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="text4" id="text4" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="text5" id="text5" /><br/>
<input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" />
<div id="result">replace</div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {

// Extract all the values into an array
var valArray = [];
$("input[type=text]").each(function(index, el) {
    valArray[index] = jQuery(el).val();
});

// Output list of values (in order they appear in form)    
$("#result").html("In order of text box: <ol id='list1'></ol>");
$.each(valArray, function(index, value) {        
    $("#list1").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
});

// Output list of values (in sorted order)
$("#result").append("In sorted order: <ol id='list2'></ol>");
valArray = valArray.sort();
$.each(valArray, function(index, value) {
    if (value != null && value != "") {
        $("#list2").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me break down your code in two part to show why it is not working yet.

```
function GetInputValues() {
    var txt = new array[];
    var txt[0] = $('input:text[name=text1]').val();
    var txt[1] = $('input:text[name=text2]').val();
    var txt[2] = $('input:text[name=text3]').val();
    var txt[3] = $('input:text[name=text4]').val();
    var txt[4] = $('input:text[name=text5]').val();
    txt.sort();
    return txt; // added by me to encapsulate getting the values
}
```

The first part of your `function myFunction()` is correct. You are using jQuery to get the values of the input boxes and writing the values into an array.

The second part has some mistakes:

```
for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('txt[i]').value + ' ';
}
```

The [function `document.getElementById("lastname")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns the html-element whose id is `lastname`. So in your for-loop you are trying to get the value but you already have the values in your array `txt`. On top this `'txt[i]'` is only a string. So javascript tries to find an element that matches `<... id="txt[i]" ...>`. But you do not want to get the values you want to write the values back into the document. Assuming you have a div like this `<div id='txt[i]'> ...</div>` you could wrhite your code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('txt[i]').innerHTML += txt[i];
}
```

Another way would be to join the array:

```
var myInputValues = GetInputValues(); // this returns your array txt
document.getElementById('myResult').InnerHTML = myInputValues.join(", ");
```

This assumes that you have a element with id=myResult for example `<div id='myResult'>..</div>`

#### Update to adress issues in your code

[Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Toral/fhe8s/) has this part:

```
myFunction(txt) {  // <-- function declaration: there is something missing here
    var myInputValues = GetInputValues(); // this returns your array txt
    document.getElementById('myResult').InnerHTML = myInputValues.join(", ");
} //<--- this is the end of myfunction
}); // <-- these do not belong here
// you never execute myFunction
```

You have to define the function and later call it. Since your mistakes are so basic i really recommend to start with a tutorial to learn javascript. I can recommend [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/):

1. to [learn the basics of functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html)
2. to understand the basics about the [Document-Object Model](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter12.html)

Comment: THnak you, I now understand how code works. I trid to put together the code you modified but looks like when i click the button, nothing happens. :( Any suggestion?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Toral/fhe8s/embedded/result/

Comment: @user3149507 I updated by answer above. I do not know if you can delete your own comments yet - in case you can please remove two of the 3 since they all have the same content.

Comment: @user3149507: If you found my answer usefull you could upvote it.